# Selecting page data from dynamic columns HtmlAgility pack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using the HtmlAgility pack to scrape data from this url:
http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/diary/chuckgross

Essentially, the only data I really need is calories, protein, fat and carbs. The issue is that these columns are user ordered (and users can even not show some of them!).

I'm trying to return that page data into a class:

```
public class NutritionRecord
    {
        public string Calories { get; set; }
        public string Protein { get; set; }
        public string Fat { get; set; }
        public string Carbs { get; set; }
    }
```

My idea was to scrape the row with the names of the columns (its a footer), and then scrape the Totals row, and then combine them into a new table, and then somehow figure out how to select the data for a column. I haven't gotten that far. This is what I have so far but feel like I'm just flailing:
http://pastebin.com/uYvMYuM3

This code returns an HTML table, and I cannot figure out how to get the data from the columns. Example in English: Give me the data in the cell whose's column header == "protein".

What the table looks like:

```
<table class='resultsTable'>
    <tr class='labels'>
        <th>Calories</th>

        <th>Protein</th>

        <th>Fat</th>

        <th>Carbs</th>

        <th>Fiber</th>
    </tr>

    <tr class='resultsTotals'>
        <td>2,386</td>

        <td>194</td>

        <td>109</td>

        <td>161</td>

        <td>38</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, you don't need to scrap the totals just generate them from the result of the following, this should take care of hidden and reordered columns

```
 public class NutritionRecord
    {
        public string Meal { get; set; }
        public string MealPart { get; set; }
        public string Calories { get; set; }
        public string Protein { get; set; }
        public string Fat { get; set; }
        public string Carbs { get; set; }
        public string Fiber { get; set; }
        public string Sugar { get; set; }
    }
```

and the scrape part:

```
       var html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://www.myfitnesspal.com/food/diary/chuckgross");
        var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
        doc.LoadHtml(html);

        var list = new List<NutritionRecord>();
        var orderedColumnsList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='meal_header']/td[@class='alt']").Select(td=>td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList();
        var trs = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr").ToList();
        for (var i = 0; i < trs.Count; i++)
        {
            bool isMealHeader = false;
            if (trs[i].Attributes["class"] != null)
            {
                isMealHeader = trs[i].Attributes["class"].Value == "meal_header";
            }

            if (isMealHeader)
            {
                var dataRows = trs[i].SelectNodes("./following-sibling::*").TakeWhile(tr => !tr.HasAttributes)
                    .Select(tr => new NutritionRecord() { 
                        Meal = WebUtility.HtmlDecode( trs[i].SelectSingleNode("./td[@class='first alt']").InnerText.Trim()), 
                        MealPart = WebUtility.HtmlDecode(tr.SelectSingleNode("./td[@class='first alt']").InnerText.Trim()),
                        Calories = tr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("./td[not(contains(@class, 'delete'))][{0}]", orderedColumnsList.IndexOf("Calories") + 2)).InnerText,
                        Protein = tr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("./td[not(contains(@class, 'delete'))][{0}]", orderedColumnsList.IndexOf("Protein") + 2)).InnerText,
                        Fat = tr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("./td[not(contains(@class, 'delete'))][{0}]", orderedColumnsList.IndexOf("Fat") + 2)).InnerText,
                        Carbs = tr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("./td[not(contains(@class, 'delete'))][{0}]", orderedColumnsList.IndexOf("Carbs") + 2)).InnerText,
                        Fiber = tr.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("./td[not(contains(@class, 'delete'))][{0}]", orderedColumnsList.IndexOf("Fiber") + 2)).InnerText,
                    });
                list.AddRange(dataRows);
            }
        }
```

and the result:

[image]

also to get the columns order get the InnerText of the column headers in order ,then use IndexOf function to get the index of the given column name, and use that index to get the value, for example

```
var orderedColumnsList = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//tr[@class='labels']/th").Select(td => td.InnerText.Trim()).ToList();
var carbsValue = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode(string.Format("//tr[@class='resultsTotals']/td[{0}]", orderedColumnsList.IndexOf("Carbs") + 1)).InnerText;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The hidden columns are a user variable and they aren't actually written to the page. I think for now I'll just have the requirement that protein/fat/carbs be shown. I am going to accept your answer as it gave me an idea to just take the selected nodes and turn them into a dictionary

Comment: var nutritionDictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            var dictionaryKeys = new List<string>();
            foreach (var cell in headerCells)
            {
                dictionaryKeys.Add(cell.InnerText);
                nutritionDictionary.Add(cell.InnerText, string.Empty);
            }

            for (int i = 0; i < dictionaryKeys.Count; i++)
            {
                nutritionDictionary[dictionaryKeys[i]] = totalCells[i].InnerText;
            }

Comment: @CGross you're welcome, also if the html is yours you can use the data-title attribute on your html table to make things easier, `<td data-title="columnName"></td>` when the column is not there or reordered it does not matter because each cell indicates its column, here is an example [link](http://www.jumpeye.com/ui-elements/tables.html)